# Replacing limit with uniformly converging sum

Tags: real-analysis

Assume we have a power series $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k} $

Which uniformly converge, say in a disk $ D(0,r) $.

Is it true that we can change the order of a limit and a sum? i.e:

$$ \lim_{x\to0}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}x^{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}\lim_{x\to0}x^{k} $$

If so, how can we prove it?

Thanks in advance, this bothers me a lot because Im not sure when changing the order of taking limits is legit.

Comment: The series converges unifornly in $|x| \leq \frac r 2$ and this implies that we can interchange the sum  and the limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The question is why uniformly convergece implies that we can interchange sum and limit

Comment: A basic result on uniform convergence says $S_n(x_n) \to S(x)$ if $x_n \to x$ and $S_n \to S$ uniformly. Take $(S_n)$ to be  the partial sum sequence of your series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n(x):=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$, then each $S_n$ is a continuous function and if $S:=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n$ converges uniformly in some open set $A$ then $S$ is continuous in $A$, that is, note that

$$
|S(x)-S(y)|\leqslant |S(x)-S_n(x)|+|S_n(x)-S_n(y)|+|S_n(y)-S(y)|\tag1
$$

Now uniform convergence imply that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is some $N\in \mathbb N $ such that $|S(z)-S_n(z)|<\epsilon $ for all $n\geqslant N$ and all $z\in A$, then from (1) we have that $|S(x)-S(y)|\leqslant 2\epsilon +|S_n(x)-S_n(y)|$ for enough large $n$ and any chosen $x,y\in A$, thus $\lim_{x\to y}|S(x)-S(y)|\leqslant 2\epsilon $ (as each $S_n$ is continuous).

Note: as $A$ is open then any point enough close to $y$ is contained in $A$, so the above limit is defined by points contained in $A$.

Finally as $\epsilon >0$ can be chosen arbitrarily small we find that $S$ is continuous in $A$, and consequently $\lim_{n\to\infty}S(x_n)=S(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n)$ for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ that is contained and converges in $A$.